# I encountered a problem while working on my project on MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, oauth, cors

I encountered a problem while working on my project on MERN Stack.

My React app is running on port 3000 and express api on 5000. What I encountered is, while adding 0auth functionality using redux, I am getting error like "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource [here](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=profile%20email&client_id=179135553003-e1nc4fhiudav4jvduad7n1dvr2hsqtj9.apps.googleusercontent.com). (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

Now the structure of my logic is like :

I have defined google strategy for passport. Defined routes in express route (http://localhost:5000/api/user/auth/google) and callback url (http://localhost:5000/api/user/auth/google/callback). Now when I am directly accessing "http://localhost:5000/api/user/auth/google", I am able to complete process, but when I am calling it through reducers from react app, I am getting above mentioned error.

My code is the following:

```
// Routes
router.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
  })

);
router.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: "/",
    session: false
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    var token = req.user.token;
    console.log(res);
    res.json({
      success: true,
      token: 'Bearer ' + token,
    });
  }
);


//Reducers Action

export const googleLoginUser = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get('api/users/auth/google')
    .then((res) => {
      //save to local Storage
      const {
        token
      } = res.data;
      // Set token to local storage
      localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
      //set token to auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      console.log(decoded);
      // set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
        })
      }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow CORS by using middleware for Express. Install CORS with `npm install cors`. Import CORS `import cors from 'cors'`. Use middleware with `app.use(cors())` if your Express-instance is called *app*.

Example:

```js
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Let me know if it solves the problem